# Get method in HTML

Tags: html, css, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have written a web server by html and css for esp8266.
I have some button in web server and I use get method in my code.
In arduino i say that when it see the name of my button ,print okk .
That is here:

```html
if(str.IndexOf("Turn+On")>0)
{
    cilent.print("Okkk"}
}
```

But the web server sends me ok every time i refresh the browser and every time i push all of the buttob.
But I want to set the command on a specific button not all of them.

I mean each Button has its own command. 
my HTML code is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
            }
            /* Style the tab */
            div.tab {
                overflow: hidden;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
            /* Style the buttons inside the tab */            
            div.tab button {
                background-color: inherit;
                float: left;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                transition: 0.3s;
                font-size: 17px;
            }
            /* Change background color of buttons on hover */            
            div.tab button:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
            /* Create an active/current tablink class */            
            div.tab button.active {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
            /* Style the tab content */            
           .tabcontent {
               display: none;
               padding: 6px 12px;
               border: 1px solid #000000;
               border-top: none;
           }            
           .button {
               position: relative;
               background-color: #C0C0C0;
               border: none;
               font-size: 28px;
               color: #FFFFFF;
               padding: 20px;
               width: 200px;
               text-align: center;
              -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
              /* Safari */
              transition-duration: 0.4s;
              text-decoration: none;
              overflow: hidden;
              cursor: pointer;
          }            
          .button:after {
              content: "";
              background: #90EE90;
              display: block;
              position: absolute;
              padding-top: 300%;
              padding-left: 350%;
              margin-left: -20px!important;
              margin-top: -120%;
              opacity: 0;
              transition: all 0.8s
          }            
          .button:active:after {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              opacity: 1;
              transition: 0s
          }
        
          body,
          html {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
          }
        
          .bg {
          /* The image used */
              background-image: url("http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/New-Age-4K-Abstract-Wallpapers.jpg");
          /* Full height */
              height: 100%;
          /* Center and scale the image nicely */
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="tab bg">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Lights')">Lights</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Digital')">Digital</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Kitchen')">Kitchen</button>
      </div>

      <div id="Lights" class="tabcontent bg">
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Bedroom1')">Bedroom1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Bedroom2')">Bedroom2</button>
          </div>       
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Hall')">Hall</button>
          </div>

          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Kitchen1')">Kitchen1</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Bedroom1" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="B1Turn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="B1Turn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      <div id="Bedroom2" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="B2Turn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="B2Turn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      
      <div id="Hall" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="HTurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="HTurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      
      <div id="Kitchen1" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="KTurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="KTurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>

      <div id="Digital" class="tabcontent bg">
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'TV')">TV</button>
          </div>
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Splitter')">Splitter</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="TV" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="TTurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="TTurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      <div id="Splitter" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="STurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="STurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      
      <div id="Kitchen" class="tabcontent bg">
          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Microvawe')">Microvawe</button>
          </div>

          <div class="tab">
              <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Refrigerator')">Refrigerator</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Microvawe" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="MTurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="MTurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      <div id="Refrigerator" class="tabcontent bg">
          <form>
              Turn On:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="RTurn On">
              <br> Turn Off:<br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="RTurn Off">
          </form>
      </div>
      
      <script>
          function Tools(evt, cityName) {
              var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
              tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
              for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
              for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
              evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
          }
      </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add an action to a form like this:

```
<form action="/url/goes/here">
```

Here is what the first two buttons would look like with this change

```
<div id="Bedroom1" class="tabcontent bg">
    <form action="/bedroom1">
        Turn On:<br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="B1Turn On">
        <br> Turn Off:<br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="B1Turn Off">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="Bedroom2" class="tabcontent bg">
    <form action="/bedroom2">
        Turn On:<br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="B2Turn On">
        <br> Turn Off:<br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="B2Turn Off">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, on your esp8266 server code, you need to check the path on each HTTP request to identify which button was pressed.

Lets say you click the "Turn On" button for Bedroom 1. The web browser responds by doing this:

```
POST /bedroom1 HTTP/1.1
... some HTTP headers will follow

Turn+On=B1Turn+On
```

It's your job to parse out the path (`/bedroom1` in the above example). Happy coding!